# Tracing Envoy's Global Rate Limit Service

Tags: rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I'm trying to get Envoy's [global rate limiting filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/other_features/global_rate_limiting) filter to participate in end to end tracing using Open Telemetry.

I have configured the filter to use Lyft's reference rate limit service and that service itself is working well. If I call it directly with a `traceparent` header in the GRPC metadata then I can see trace data emitted with the expected `trace_id`.

Moreover, when I call the rate *limited* service via Envoy with a `traceparent` header it also emits traces with the expected `trace_id`.

However, Envoy doesn't seem to forward the header to the rate *limiter* service. When testing end-to-end via Envoy, the reference service doesn't appear to receive the header and its traces aren't integrated with those of the service being rate limited.

Is this supposed to 'just work'? Am I missing some configuration on the Envoy side?